# Is the parametrization $(t^3,t^6)$, a reparametrization of $(t,t^2)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have gathered that it is not. But I find it to obey all the conditions of being a reparametrization. Definition given in comments :P

Comment: If $(t,t^2)$ is a parametrisation of $y=x^2$, then it can be seen that $(t^3,t^6)$ satisfies the equation also. Thus it is a re-parametrisation.

Comment: But a theorem says that the reparametrization of a regular curve is regular. And here, $(t,t^2)$ is regular but $(t^3,t^6)$ is not at t=0. @Cataline

Comment: Obviously that theorem depends on the definition of "reparametrisation".

Comment: What's your definition of reparametrization? Using the one I know, Cataline's statement is false.

Comment: From A. Pressley's Differential Geometry text, A parametrized curve $\tilde{\gamma}:(\tilde{\alpha} , \tilde{\beta})\rightarrow R^n$ is a reparametrization of a parametrized curve $\gamma:(\alpha , \beta)\rightarrow R^n$ if there is a smooth bijective map $\phi:(\tilde{\alpha} , \tilde{\beta})\rightarrow (\alpha , \beta)$ (the reparametrization map) such that the inverse map $\phi^-1 :(\alpha , \beta)\rightarrow (\tilde{\alpha} , \tilde{\beta})$ is also smooth and $\tilde{\gamma}(\tilde{t})= \gamma (\phi(\tilde{t}))$ for all $\tilde{t} \epsilon (\tilde{\alpha} , \tilde{\beta})$. @ZhenLin

Comment: Also to the previous comment I would add from the text that since $\phi$ has a smooth inverse, $\gamma$ is a reparametrization of $\tilde{\gamma}$: $\tilde{\gamma}=\gamma(\phi(\phi^-1(t)))=\gamma(t)$ for all  $ t  \epsilon  (\alpha,\beta)$. And please explain why two curves that are reparamtrizations of each other have the same image and thus same geometric properties.

Comment: Well, then you don't have a reparametrisation, because the inverse is not smooth.

Comment: So, can I conclude that reparametrizations can't have the parameter raised to some power because its inverse would have a fractional power which will be reduced to the denominator after differentiating some n times and hence not continuous at zero? @ZhenLin